# My iPad mini from apple isn't turning on

Tags: ipad, power

I have a mini iPad from apple for a few years now and never once has it played up. This morning however it refused to turn on (it was working fine last night). I have been charging it almost all day so it can't be out of charge. I have also held the power and home button for forever but nothing has happened at all. I'm stressing so if someone could hep I would be very grateful. I have tried a lot of things so I'm almost out of hope. I don't want to take it into the apple store just yet so I'm hoping you have something for me. Thank you.

Comment: Try removing all cords from the device, then hold the power and the Home Button again

Comment: Also try charging with a different cable and charger.